# android, use camera as a background for an activity

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a request that background for my activity must be "transparent", ie. background of an activity should be camera's current view. What is the easiest way to implemet this? 
I have all the activities already implemented, with all the logic already implemented. Ideally, solution wouldn't include a lot of modification of an existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this is done with `SurfaceView`. Use it via `camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView)`

To use it in your app, the simplest way would be to use `FrameLayout` as a top layout of your Activity and then put `SurfaceView` any you current top layout inside it.

```
`FrameLayout`
    `SurfaceView`
    `yourExistingLayout`
```

Of course your existing layout must be transparent to see the underlying `SurfaceView`. Note also that this alpha blending takes a lot of processor power so it will eat battery.